# WPF + Toast gives error The type or namespace name 'Toolkit' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: powershell, toast

In my WPF project, I use Windows toast messages using `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications`.
I put all the code related to toast messages in a separate project and referenced it from main project.
If the project is built directly from  Visual Studio it compiles and works as expected. But if I try to build it from Developer Powershell with `dotnet build .` command it returns the following message

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Toolkit' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Build FAILED.
```

Any ideas? Googling for days doesn't help